# how to separate 2 numbers within a column in R

Tags: r, dataset

In R, I want to separate numbers that are in the same column. My data appear like this:

```
id   time       
1    1,2    
2    3,4    
3    4,5,6
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
1    1
1    2
2    3
2    4
3    4
3    5
3    6
```

Though not shown, there are different iterations of time that vary depending on the id. For example:

```
4    1,6,7      
5    1,3,6    
6    1,4,5    
7    1,3,5    
8    2,3,4
```

There are 100 ids and the time column has different #s that vary in order as shown above.

Does anyone have advice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you could try the following. Make sure `time` is `character` type, and use `strsplit` to split up into single characters.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(time = strsplit(as.character(time), ",")) %>%
  unnest(cols = time)
```

Or you can just use `separate_rows` and indicate comma as separator:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(time, sep = ',')
```

Or in base R you could try this:

```
s <- strsplit(df$time, ',', fixed = T)
data.frame(id = unlist(s), time = rep(df$id, lengths(s)))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id time 
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 1    
 2     1 2    
 3     2 3    
 4     2 4    
 5     3 4    
 6     3 5    
 7     3 6    
 8     4 1    
 9     4 6    
10     4 7
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, time = c("1,2", "3,4", "4,5,6", "1,6,7"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! The time column actually varies from 1-7. So, there are variations actually like this.

Comment: Hi Ben. A couple of things.  The data are appearing not quite correctly. For example, for the first id and first row, they are appearing with an id (1 in col 1) and a 1 (col2). In the next row, there is a the same id (1 in col 1) and a comma in column 2. There is a third row that has the same id (1 in col 1) and a 2 in column 2. How can I revise the code to make sure no comma is included?

Comment: Hi Ben. Gah! Yes, it is separated by commas. I didn't want to post a sample of the day because of confidentiality issues, but I have revised the code above to capture the data better. I did not try akrun's answer as I wasn't sure how to modify it to fit my needs. My apologies for not better characterizing my data and structure.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. The thing is that there are a number of iterations for time that are not shown (the # of rows is close to 100). So, for example, time also includes 1,2,3, or 4,8,9. Close to probably 60 different variations and I am hoping to not right out all of those in the c column.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean when I say I don't want to write out all the permutations of time. In other words, in your code, I would have to indicate all the values that time can take, which is a lot. Based on my example, I would have to add, df <- structure(list(id = 1:8, time = c("1,2", "3,4", "4,5,6", "1,6,7", "6,1,3", "1,4,5", "3,5,1", "2,3,4"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)).  By time, I essentially mean visits. I'm concerned that I may make a mistake in writing out all the time or visit options as there are a lot of them. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Ohh, I see. The time (or visit variable) is actually organized in ascending order which I have reflected above. So, ID 4 would have 4,6,7 not the other ones. Another participant (say ID 25) could have 3,6,7 or 1,5,6. That's what I meant about their being different time iterations, although they go from low values (reflecting few visits (e.g., 1) to more visits (reflecting more visits (e.g., 7). Does that help?

Comment: Ben, it DID work. I didn't think it would, but I got confused with part of your code. Apologies for the misunderstanding and than you for your patience and time!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

An option with `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 separate_rows(time, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     id  time
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     2     3
#4     2     4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), time = c(12, 34)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```